# sails js and postgres database with few different schemas and same table names in different schemas

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sails.js

I've encountered a huge problem with sails and sails-postgresql.

I'm using sails v 0.10.0-rc8 and sails-postgresql v 0.10.0-rc4

I have postgres database with few diffrent schemas for different applications.

These schemas contains some tables with exactly same name for example:

schema test has table uzytkownicy (users) and schema webApp also has table uzytkownicy but with some diffrent attributes.

Somehow sails with sails-postgresql join all tables with same name from all schemas into one huge table (which dont exists in database) and throw errors when im trying to get some data from table defined in my model.

Example:

my model definition:

```
module.exports = {

  adapter: 'postgresql_app',
  tableName: 'uzytkownicy',
  migrate: 'safe',
  autoPK: false,
  autoCreatedAt: false,
  autoUpdatedAt: false,

  meta: {
    schemaName: 'webApp'
  },

  attributes: {

    id_uzytkownicy: {
        type: 'integer',
        index: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },

    id_role: {
        model: 'role'
    },

    imie: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },

    nazwisko: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },

    username: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    }

  }
};
```

my sails-postgresql configuration:

```
postgresql_app: {
    adapter: 'sails-postgresql',
    host: '<IP_ADRESS>',
    user: '<USERNAME>',
    port: '<PORT>',
    database: '<DATABASE>',
    password: '<PASSWORD>'
}
```

Now from sails console model definition (only partial output from sails> Uzytkownicy):

```
 usernameContains: [Function: bound],
  usernameEndsWith: [Function: bound],
  definition:
   { id_uzytkownicy:
      { type: 'integer',
        index: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        unique: true },
     id_role:
      { type: 'integer',
        model: 'role',
        foreignKey: true },
     imie: { type: 'string' },
     nazwisko: { type: 'string' },
     username: { type: 'string' } },
  meta:
   { schemaName: 'webApp',
     junctionTable: false },
  schema:
   { id_uzytkownicy:
      { type: 'integer',
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true },
     id_role: { type: 'integer' },
     imie: { type: 'text' },
     nazwisko: { type: 'text' },
     username: { type: 'character varying(128)' },
     login: { type: 'character varying(64)' },
     test: { type: 'timestamp with time zone' },
     id_stanowisko: { type: 'integer' },
     id_wydzial: { type: 'integer' },
     id_firma: { type: 'integer' },
     id_rodzaj_umowy: { type: 'integer' },
     id_osoby_z_ifs: { type: 'integer', unique: true },
     id_przelozonego: { type: 'integer' },
     sha_password: { type: 'text' },
     pozostale_dni_urlopu: { type: 'integer' },
     edytowany: { type: 'boolean' },
     id_uzytkownika: { type: 'numeric', primaryKey: true },
     id_roli: { type: 'numeric' },
     zalogowany: { type: 'boolean' } },
  alter: [Function: bound],
  buildDynamicFinders: [Function: bound],
```

definition attribute is correct but schema attribute contains fields combined from all tables uzytkownicy from diffrent schemas.

When I want to get some data:

```
sails> Uzytkownicy.find({}).exec(console.log)
```

Im getting exception:

```
sails> Uzytkownicy.find({}).exec(console.log)
Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
error: column uzytkownicy.login does not exists
    at Connection.parseE (/home/aplikacje/www/nodejs/webApp/trunk/node_modules/sails-postgresql/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:526:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/home/aplikacje/www/nodejs/webApp/trunk/node_modules/sails-postgresql/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:356:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/aplikacje/www/nodejs/webApp/trunk/node_modules/sails-postgresql/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:105:22)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:746:14)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:404:5)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:127:10)

Details:  error: column uzytkownicy.login does not exists
```

What is true because my webApp.uzytkownicy does not has column login, it exists in diffrent schema!

However creating (Uzytkownicy.create()) data works perfectly and data is inserted only into my webApp.uzytkownicy table.

Am I doing something wrong in configuration? I want to use only schema webApp without interactions with other schemas.

Comment: I've found temporary solution to bypass that problem:

In file ./config/bootstrap can be added Users.schema = Users.definition; which set table schema to correct one and allow to sucessfully find() data from table in selected database schema.

Comment: I have the same problem..but across 2 different database systems...would be nice to hear from the devs on this

Comment: Same error here. It only updates public schema. Regardless of the schemaName set.